# Handling box constraints in Nelder-Mead optimisation by distorting the parameter space

Tags: r, algorithm, nonlinear-optimization, heuristics

I have a question on a specific implementation of a Nelder-Mead algorithm (1) that handles box contraints in an unusual way. I cannot find in anything about it in any paper (25 papers), textbook (searched 4 of them) or the internet.

I have a typical optimisation problem: `min f(x)` with a box constraint `-0.25 <= x_i <= 250`

The expected approach would be using a penalty function and make sure that all instances of `f(x)` are "unattractive" when x is out of bounds.

The algorithm works differently: the implementation in question does not touch `f(x)`. Instead it distorts the parameter space using an inverse hyperbolic tangens `atanh(f)`. Now the simplex algorithm can freely operate in a space without bounds and pick just any point. Before it gets `f(x)` in order to assess the solution at x the algorithm switches back into normal space.

At a first glance I found the idea ingenious. This way we avoid the disadvantages of penalty functions. But now I am having doubts. The distorted space affects termination behaviour. One termination criterion is the size of the simplex. By inflating the parameter space with `atanh(x)` we also inflate the simplex size.

Experiments with the algorithm also show that it does not work as intended. I do not yet understand how this happens, but I do get results that are out of bounds. I can say that almost half of the returned local minima are out of bounds.

As an example, take a look at nmkb() optimising the rosenbrook function when we gradually change the width of the box constraint:

```
rosbkext <- function(x) {
  # Extended Rosenbrock function
  n <- length(x)
  sum (100*(x[1:(n-1)]^2 - x[2:n])^2 + (x[1:(n-1)] - 1)^2)
}

np <- 6 #12
for (box in c(2, 4, 12, 24, 32, 64, 128)) {
  set.seed(123)
  p0 <- rnorm(np)
  p0[p0 > +2] <- +2 - 1E-8
  p0[p0 < -2] <- -2 + 1E-8

  ctrl <- list(maxfeval = 5E4, tol = 1E-8)
  o <- nmkb(fn = rosbkext, par = p0, lower = -box, upper = +box, control = ctrl)
  print(o$message)
  cat("f(", format(o$par, digits = 2), ") =", format(o$value, digits=3), "\n")
}
```

The output shows that it claims to converge but it does not in three cases. And it does that for bounds of (-2,2) and (-12,12). I might accept that but then it also fails at (-128, 128). I also tried the same with the unconstrained dfoptim::nmk(). No trouble there. It converges perfectly.

```
[1] "Successful convergence"
f( -0.99  0.98  0.97  0.95  0.90  0.81 ) = 3.97 
[1] "Successful convergence"
f( 1 1 1 1 1 1 ) = 4.42e-09 
[1] "Successful convergence"
f( -0.99  0.98  0.97  0.95  0.90  0.81 ) = 3.97 
[1] "Successful convergence"
f( 1 1 1 1 1 1 ) = 1.3e-08 
[1] "Successful convergence"
f( 1 1 1 1 1 1 ) = 4.22e-09 
[1] "Successful convergence"
f( 1 1 1 1 1 1 ) = 8.22e-09 
[1] "Successful convergence"
f( -0.99  0.98  0.97  0.95  0.90  0.81 ) = 3.97
```

Why does the constrained algorithm have more trouble converging than the unconstrained one?

---

Footnote (1):  I am referring to the Nelder-Mead implementation used in the optimx package in R. This package calls another package dfoptim with the nmkb-function.

Comment: It could be a local optimum (after transformation).

Comment: It most likely is. My point rather is that the unconstrained algorithm does not have any trouble finding the global optimum. Adding the constraint causes trouble. In the discussion with @Hans W he suggested that it could be about the spatial distortion that the algorithm uses to inflate the bounded space to an unbounded one. That could give me trouble when the optimum lies close to the bounds. But that does not seem to be the case.

Now I am looking for inspiration because right now, I have no idea how to solve this. Is there a reason or am I just overlooking something?

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen  No, Rosenbrock does not have a local optimum there.
As I point out below, using a different implementation of Nelder-Mead, the solution comes out perfectly. It is a kind of bug in `nmkb()` and I suggest to inform the maintainer of the *dfoptim* package.

Comment: Is it still convex after applying the transform?

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thanks, that was a good tip. Rosenbrock is not convex in higher dimensions and the weird point above appears to be a local minimum -- not only of the transformed, but also of the real function `rosbkext()`. `optim` too (and others) stop at that point. So it's probably not a bug in the Nelder-Mead implementation.

Comment: @HansW.Thanks for further analyzing this. Lucky guess on my side (well, the reported solutions made me suspicious).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This question has nothing to do with `optimx`, which is just a wrapper for R packages providing unconstrained optimization.)

The function in question is `nmkb()` in the *dfoptim* package for gradient-free optimization routines. The approach to transform bounded regions into unbounded spaces is a common one and can be applied with many different transformation functions, sometimes depending on the kind of the boundary and/or the type of the objective function. It may also be applied, e.g., to transform unbounded integration domains into bounded ones.

The approach is problematic if the optimum lies at the boundary, because the optimal point will be sent to (nearly) infinity and cannot ultimately be reached. The routine will not converge or the solution be quite inaccurate.

If you think the algorithm is not working correctly, you should write to the authors of that package and -- that is important -- add one or two examples for what you think are bugs or incorrect solutions. Without explicit code examples no one here is able to help you.

(1) Those transformations define bijective maps between bounded and unbounded regions and the theory behind this approach is obvious. You may read about possible transformations in books on multivariate calculus.

(2) The approach with penalties outside the bounds has its own drawbacks, for instance the target function will not be smooth at the boundaries, and the BFGS method may not be appropriate anymore.

(3) You could try the Hooke-Jeeves algorithm through function `hjkb()` in the same *dfoptim* package. It will be slower, but uses a different approach for treating the boundaries, no transformations involved.

**EDIT** (after discussion with Erwin Kalvelagen above)

There appear to be local minima (with some coordinates negative).
If you set the lower bounds to 0, `nmkb()` will find the global minimum `(1,1,1,1,1,1)` in any case.
Watch out: starting values have to be feasible, that is all their coordinates greater 0.

Comment: Thank you Hans. I will have a look at hjkb().

Comment: And please apologize my nitpicking, but as I said in my footnote I am aware that nmkb() is from the dfoptim package. I have the code right here which is how I realised that it uses the simplex size as termination criterion (among others) which must be problematic when I distort the space. Do you have any experience with that? The only solution I can think of is to re-write the simplex size statement, i.e. to go into "normal" space before calculating the simplex size.

Comment: @Jan Me and many others have used `nmkb()` successfully. The size of the simplex plays a role only if the optimum is near the boundary(!), which is the region that somehow gets 'distorted'. If you have problems with this approach, we need some examples and code from you, otherwise there is no way to help.

Comment: Thank you so much @Hans for taking the time. Discussing it with someone helps. I added an example to the question. For some reason the constrained version has more trouble converging. When you remove set.seed() and run this you can see that it repeatedly fails to do so. It does not depend on the width of the bounds. I also tried asymmetric bounds. And I found out that it is not the simplex.size that terminates the loop. That makes even less sense.

Comment: @Jan I checked your example with the Nelder-Mead implementation in *pracma*, using the explicit transformation `transfinite` in *adagio*. In every case the result was `(1 1 1 1 1 1)` (with max. 1e-16 deviation). So there seems to be something wrong in `nmkb()`. I definitely suggest you send a bug report to the maintainer of the *dfoptim* package!

Comment: Sorry @Hans-W I cannot replicate it with lower bounds = 0. When I do the same the unconstrained function finds the global optimum in 95% of 5000 runs. The constrained one misses the global optimum in 95% of the runs, in many cases it fails to converge completely, and every now and then the function terminates with an error "Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular". 

Unless I make some bad rookie mistake, there is most def something wrong with `nmkb`. Check it out if you are still interested. I put it here: https://gist.github.com/SigurdJanson/b7f1ee43cf4c3d5788aa26b4c828ebb4

Comment: Sorry @Jan this thread is too long now, and is closed for me. If you still have problems, open a new question with reproducible code or, as I have said too often by now, write to the maintainer.